# AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`item1`' given input columns: [];

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I used AWS Glue Transform-custom code, and wrote the following code.

```py
def MyTransform (glueContext, dfc) -> DynamicFrameCollection:

    from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit
    selected = dfc.select(list(dfc.keys())[0]).toDF()
    selected = selected.withColumn('item2',lit(col('item1')))
    results = DynamicFrame.fromDF(selected, glueContext, "results")
    return DynamicFrameCollection({"results": results}, glueContext)
```

I got the following error.

```
AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`item1`' given input columns: [];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wrap `lit(col('item1'))`. `lit` is used to create a literal static value, while `col` is to refer to a specific column. Depends on what exactly you're trying to achieve, but this change will at least fix your error

```py
selected = selected.withColumn('item2', col('item1'))
```

Comment: great, feel free to accept the answer and close the thread